# API Management Tool Recommendation

Tags: jmeter, api-testing, api, katalon, postman

I am looking for a tool for API testing and collaboration that offers the following:

1. Creating a workspace that can be shared with a limited number of people.
2. A good number of collections without being archived.

I am using Postman (free) right now and I can host only 5 collections that are shared with everyone in the organization. Beyond 5 collections, the collections get archived.

Looking for something free or economic as I can't pay 15 USD per user month right now. We are 4-6 users bootstrapping right now so please keep that in mind while suggesting options.

Comment: You can export/import collections, and version them on GIt e.g.

Answer (score 2):

For functional API testing you can consider using [**SoapUI**](https://www.soapui.org/), it provides unlimited [workspaces/projects](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/working-with-soapui/managing-workspaces.html) and [immense features list even for open-source free version](https://www.soapui.org/open-source/features.html) including assertions, mocks, scripting, automation, support of OAuth and WS Security, SAML, NTLM, security testing features, limited load testing features, support of SOAP, REST, AMF, MQTT, JDBC, JMS, etc.

Probably SoapUI is the most advanced web services (and more) testing tool you can find for free.

If you need to conduct performance testing of the web services the best candidate is **[Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)**, it supports more or less the same protocols (including [SOAP and REST web services](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter/)) but it can create unlimited load and has much better reporting of protocol-related performance metrics via [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: I need something where I can create an account and is hosted so I can share the collection. Can you suggest something in that direction.

Comment: You can share your projects in version control systems. For example bitbucket has a free plan that allows to create private repositories.

Comment: In postman you can create a workspace and collections within them and share the collection with team members. If you want to share it with limited number of people or make the workspace private you need to subscribe to their premium plan. I need a service where I can get that functionality without having to pay as much.

Comment: @AlexeyR. How can I use github or bitbucket to host my api collection?  Isnt that for sharing the code?

Comment: It is for storing the sources. Not just the code. SoapUI stores the project as xml-file. You can put it to a prepo as any other file. So you would not just having a shared "collection" but also a versioned one.

Answer (score 1):

For your needs the best tool is Swagger

[Swagger](https://editor.swagger.io/) - here you can check how the API page will look like

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is free and allows you to conduct functional and performance testing of APIs so I'd recommend that.

SoapUI is free also but lacks on the performance testing side. It does however cater better for security testing vs JMeter.

There is a paid-for version of SoapUI (SoapUI Pro) but these can start to get expensive.

I'd recommend JMeter.

Comment: I need something where I can create an account and is hosted so I can share the collection. Can you suggest something in that direction.

Comment: You can source control your JMeter collection so anyone you need to can access it. This also means that others can work on it and can always get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Rest assured framework if you want to implement API testing with java. This is a popular framework these days.
you can create a repository in git and achieve the collaboration you require.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Rest assured with Java. Now a days market leading technology.
2. Cypress.IO

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you were to explain why the two choices you have made are good choices. "market leading technology" isn't enough - every tool makes that claim somewhere in its marketing.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway from Amazon might be worth exploring given all the supporting infrastructure that comes with it.

https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/